# How do we call this theorem? Fubini's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

My question is really simple. I'm reading a book which states this theorem:

> If $f:A_1\times A_2\to \mathbb R$ is integrable and $f$ is continuous then
>
> $$\int_{A_1\times A_2}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{A_1}dx\bigg(\int_{A_2}f(x,y)dy\bigg)=\int_{A_2}dy\bigg(\int_{A_1}f(x,y)dx\bigg)$$

Is this Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Fubini's Theorem cover a more general case. But yes.

Comment: It's a similar result to Fubini's theorem but has stronger assumptions (continuity is not required for the result to hold)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem